# Struts 2 interface after execution of action

Tags: struts2

Is there any struts2 interface after the execution of the action

Preparable is for before the execution of action like that do we have  anything after the execution of action ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do execute some method before and after action execution, you can use the following annotations but you need to configure [AnnotationWorkflowInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/annotationworkflowinterceptor.html)

[@Before](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/before-annotation.html)

[@After](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/after-annotation.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. (Nor am I sure why you'd want such a thing.)

Easiest options:

- Create your own Preparable-like interceptor that does this.
- Create a base action class that calls to a subclass with the actual action method.
- Use AOP, e.g., with Spring or AspectJ.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what is your scenario, but I think this maight be what you are looking for: [Execute And Wait Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [PreResultListener](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/preresultlistener.html) interface.  Implementing it from an action is not the prettiest.

An example usage of this interface for your purpose could be to create an abstract support class such as:

```
public abstract class PreResultSupport extends ActionSupport implements PreResultListener {

    protected abstract String doExecute();

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        ActionContext.getContext().getActionInvocation().addPreResultListener(this);
        return doExecute();
    }

}
```

Then, for actions that you want to do some "post-preparing" for, you could extend this support class:

```
public class ExampleAction extends PreResultSupport {

    private String instanceField;

    @Override
    protected String doExecute() {
        //your action code here
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeResult(ActionInvocation invocation, String resultCode) {
        //your "post-prepare" or "view-prepare" code here
        //this is threadsafe as well, so you can still reference class fields:
        this.instanceField = "blahblahblah";
    }

}
```